# Impact of identical GUID across applications

Tags: c#, assemblies, guid

Whenever I have a new C# project, I often copy/rename an existing one in order to re-use most of the code. This means going into Assembly Info and renaming the project in there as well. In the past, I haven't really bothered with renaming the GUID.

Is this bad programming practice and could it negatively impact the user if they have another program open with the same GUID?

I am by no means an expert programmer, but I get by and I figure things out as I go along. Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the GUIDs are used for. Some re-uses of GUIDs that I know that *can* cause severe (and yet subtle) complications are:

1. GUIDs exposed to COM in any way. If two COM components with the same GUIDs are ever registered there will be very confusing and near-impossible-to-resolve conflicts.
2. GUIDs which are product IDs in setup projects. It isn't very fun to run into a situation where a *different* product is uninstalled and/or otherwise prevents installation.
3. Most GUIDs in SharePoint. (Column types, timer jobs, etc.)

In the end, I would look for other methods of "re-use" if possible.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

I would say blind copy/paste vs smart re-use is in general a bad practice, but if you update the values in the assemblyInfo you might be on the safe side.

Personally I always assign a different Guid to every project if I copy that file, but anyway the `AssemblyGuid` attribute is used only for COM interoperability so if you are making pure .NET class libraries or applications and you have `ComVisible` set to false because you don't expose anything via `COM`, you shouldn't worry and there wont be any impact on anything else.

Comment: Thanks, Davide! If I could choose two acceptable answers, I would :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are copy/pasting so often, consider extracting the common code into a library and referencing it from your other projects. This has advantages due the reduced maintenance when you make a change of fix a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know .Net, but in most languages you can package reusable code into a library.  Keep the source to your library in just one project, then link to the binary of the library from each of your main applications.

If you persist with the copy-n-paste code reuse, you will quickly find that maintenance becomes a nightmare.  It's much better that reusable code be kept in one place so that when you fix a bug, it's fixed for all of the programs that use it.